# Importing Active Directory OU's to SCCM with thru PowerShell Code

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sccm, active-directory-group

I need to move my OU's in my Active Directory to SCCM Device Collections using Power Shell. Basically replication AD OU's in SCCM.

I have tried to create device collections based off of active directory OU structures but I have hundreds of collections and it takes a while to create one. This is something we have to do in monthly basis in our case. I'm a newbie so I might have asked a very basic question...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFzTe.jpg is the OU's I have for each department, and according to each department I am trying to have a device collection in SCCM.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm5Ph.jpg is the SCCM device collection snap shot.

Answer (score 1):

Just use …

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*' | 
Select Name,DistinguishedName
```

… to get your OU data.

So, since your are new to this, that's fine, but, please spend time on YouTube, MSDN Channel9, Microsoft Virtual Academy, Microsoft Learning to take the visual approach to getting up to speed. Just search for PowerShell presentations / training and PowerShell Active Directory. To get up to speed.

Comment: tbf this is only half the work. To create a collection in sccm you would need the sccm cmdlets (automatically installed on any pc with sccm console) and then create every name you got from your first query with New-CmCollection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/new-cmcollection?view=sccm-ps) afterwards move it where you want with Move-CMObject (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/move-cmobject?view=sccm-ps)